How to watch node_modules/sdk/src in a vitejs project?
We have a vitejs web project and 3 local sdks (built by vitejs' lib mode).
The web project depends on the 3 sdks (through yarn link)
CURRRENT SITUATION:
Currently we have to start 4 watches (yarn dev) in 4 folders (1 project + 3 sdks), so that when we make a code change in sdk1, it auto builds into node_modules/sdk1/dist, and the web project can consume the change and reflect on the browser.
IDEAL SITUATION:
Ideally we only have to start 1 watch (yarn dev) in web project only, and it can auto watch node_modules/sdk1/src, auto build, so that code changes in sdk1/2/3 can all be auto detected and reflected on the browser. Is it possible?
References:

https://dev.to/receter/how-to-create-a-react-component-library-using-vites-library-mode-4lma
https://dev.to/pitops/how-to-develop-a-local-package-and-use-in-a-vite-app-1hb3
https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling

